# Read all files in folder through file dialog

Tags: javascript

I was using folder dialog which gets all files in a folder and then through FILELIST API i can read all files. Mycode for folder dialog is and filereading is as follows:

```
 document.getElementById('files').onchange = function(e) {
        // Retrieve the file list from the input element
      /*  var control = $("#files");
        control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
         */
        alert("On Change function called:");
        Files =e.target.files;
        readFiles=e.target.files;
        for (var i in e.target.files)
        {
e.target.files[i].webkitRelativePath+"\n";

            if(e.target.files[i].webkitRelativePath!=undefined)
                {

                    {

                    console.log("Path: "+e.target.files[i].webkitRelativePath) ;
                    var reader = new FileReader();

 reader.readAsText(e.target.files[i]); 
}
```

Now what i want is that there will be a file dialog and user chooses a file and all files placed in the folder from where user chooses a file are pushed in FILELIST and then i will read all files from above code. i am stuck in how to push file FileLIST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to read all files placed in folder as javascript dont allow you to read all files. Path for all files are encrypted. So i resolve this issue by allowing user to select multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with only supporting HTML5-capable browsers, you can  and get this behavior. Let the user select all the files by using **Ctrl-A** or Selected multiple files only.

and I would go for already implemented javascript library such as [qq/Valums File Uploader](http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/)
Which provides number of features and events, for a quick view
*[How to implement multiple files uploading? With Django and valums file-uploader it's easy](http://nanvel.name/weblog/file-uploader/)*

Comment: i dun want user to choose multiple files i want user choose 1 file and i manually push other file